# Multi-targetted Library (monoandroid, xamarinios) issue with System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2022, multitargeting

I'm converting a (working) .netstandard library project into a multi-targetted project that will target:

`<targetframeworks>netstandard2.1;xamarinios10;monoandroid10.0;monoandroid12.0;</targetframeworks>`

I'm having issues with the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations reference.  Sepcifically I get this error (for eveything except the .netstandard target):

`The type 'DataType' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.`

After a bit of searching I tried adding the System.ComponentModel.Annotations (4.7.0) nuget package.  This gave the same error.

In the nuget directory for this I noticed that where the .dll would normally live it had a file '*.*' - I didn't know if that was important (.nuget\packages\system.componentmodel.annotations\4.7.0\ref\MonoAndroid10) - the .netstandard dll was there as expected.

I've also noticed that (a separate) Xamarin.Android project seems to use the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll which lives in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\Xamarin.iOS\v1.0

I'm not sure if the right version of Mono.Android (or ios equivalant) is being targetted or I have to specify a specific assembly version, or whether I'm down the wrong track completely?

Thanks in advance,
Paul.

Comment: Try adding a reference to it in Reference Paths.

Comment: This may work - but when the CI pipeline runs this path isn't going to be available

Comment: Have you tried adding? Error didn't change?

Comment: I ended up putting the problem bit of code (and the nuget reference) into a seperate project and then referencing it in my multi-targeted project - this worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comment above mentions, to workaround this issue, I moved the bit of offending code (that used the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations) into a seperate project that targetted .netstandard2.1 and then referenced this project from my multi-targetted project.